# Displaying DATE only

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi guys how do i make it display date only.
temp.StartDate.Date doesnt work, it display as 3/5/2012 12:00:00

I tried

```
temp.StartDate.Date
temp.StartDate
temp.StartDate.ToShortDateString
temp.StartDate.Date.ToShortDateString
```

Here is my code

```
List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach(sMedication temp in medicationList) 
    {
        if (dateList.Contains(temp.StartDate.Date))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            dateList.Add((temp.StartDate.Date));

        }
    }
    lstboxSchedule.ItemsSource = date
```

List;

Comment: `ToShortDateString` should work. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: How are you setting up the display part ? i believe yours is DateTime List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code modifies the values, but doesn't convert them *for display*

So something like this will convert your strings for display:

```
List<string> dateList = new List<string>();
foreach(sMedication temp in medicationList) 
{
    if (!dateList.Contains(temp.StartDate.ToShortDateString()))
    {
        dateList.Add((temp.StartDate.ToShortDateString()));
    }
}
lstboxSchedule.ItemsSource = date
```

Comment: Thank you sir,
(!dateList.Contains(temp.StartDate.ToShortDateString())) really helped >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
temp.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Please don't impose a date format on your users (especially not such a braindead one). They can configure that in their phone and apps should use the configured one.

Comment: @Joey: I understand your reason, but my "*Try using*" is to tell OP to try if it works. I'm not imposing anything, I'm suggesting him a try... but ok, I respect your point.

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
Hmm, Thanks for helping Marco!

Comment: @RainbowHat: can you show us variables types please? Is temp a string or a date? And StartDate?

Comment: `ToShortDateString` is a much safer approach (and more likely to pass certification)